# Build a dynamic query using neo4j client

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I read many questions on this topic and created the following almost dynamic query:

```
var resQuery = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
                .Match("(movie:Movie {title:{title}})")
                .WithParam("title", title)
                .Return(() => new {
                    movie = Return.As<string>("movie.title")
                }).Results;
```

Unfortunately this isn't dynamic since I'm declaring the movie property in the Return anonymous type.

In all the examples I found the only option is to return the nodes as an object matches the node properties,
like: `movie = Return.As<string>("movie.title")`

I want the Return statement to give me back a key-value pair list of all the node properties (it can be in any representation like JSON etc..), since
my nodes are generic and not from a specific object kind every time.

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var resQuery = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(movie:Movie {title:{title}})")
    .WithParam("title", title)
    .Return(() => Return.As<Node<Dictionary<string,string>>>("movie"));

var results = resQuery.Results.Select(r => r.Data);
Console.WriteLine(results.First()["title"]);
```

Alternatively, something like:

```
var resQuery = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(movie:Movie {title:{title}})")
    .WithParam("title", title)
    .Return(() => Return.As<Node<string>>("movie"));

var results = resQuery.Results;
List<dynamic> nodes = results.Select(r => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(r.Data)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(nodes[0].title);
```

Comment: Thanks!
What if I want to add more return values? 

       e.g. 
`cast = Return.As<IEnumerable<string>>("collect([person.name, head(split(lower(type(r)), '_')), r.roles])")`

Comment: @DorCohen do you mean as in `.Return((x,y,z) => new {X = x.As<>(), Y=` etc?

Comment: But this will ruin the dynamic, is it possible to return multiple nodes? something like: `.Return(() => Return.As<string>("movie, collect([person.name, head(split(lower(type(r)), '_')), r.roles])"));`

Comment: Yes, but could you ask another question as I think it'll get too big for me to write in a comment!

Comment: New question opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008354/returning-multi-value-in-dynamic-query-using-neo4j-client