# Returning multi value in dynamic query using neo4j client

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Following the question I asked: [Build a dynamic query using neo4j client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006264/build-a-dynamic-query-using-neo4j-client/36007551?noredirect=1#comment59668013_36007551)

I got an answer about how can I return value dynamically using string only.

When I'm trying to use the syntax to return multi values from the query it failed,
I tried the following query:

```
var resQuery2 = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(movie:Movie {title:{title}})")
            .OptionalMatch("(movie)<-[r]-(person:Person)")
            .WithParam("title", title)
            .Return(() => Return.As<string>("movie, collect([person.name, head(split(lower(type(r)), '_')), r.roles])"));
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The deserializer is running in single column mode, but the response
>   included multiple columns which indicates a projection instead. If
>   using the fluent Cypher interface, use the overload of Return that
>   takes a lambda or object instead of single string. (The overload with
>   a single string is for an identity, not raw query text: we can't map
>   the columns back out if you just supply raw query text.)

Is it possible to return multiple nodes using only strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't get an output like in the question you asked previously - this is due to the fact that you are asking for a Node (the `movie`) and a Collection of strings (the `collect`) and they have no common properties, or even styles of property.

Firstly, let's look at the painful way to do this:

```
var q = gc.Cypher
    .Match("(movie:Movie)")
    .OptionalMatch("(movie)<-[r]-(person:Person)")
    .Return(() => Return.As<string>("{movie:movie, roles:collect([person.name, head(split(lower(type(r)), '_')), r.roles])}"));

var results = q.Results;
```

Here we take the query items (`movie, r, person`) and create a type with them the `{}` around the results, and cast that to a `string`.

This will give you a horrible string with the `Node` data around the `movie` and then a collection of the roles:

```
foreach (var m in results)
{
    //This is going to be painful to navigate/use
    dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(m);
    Console.WriteLine(d.movie);
    Console.WriteLine(d.roles);
}
```

You'd be a lot better off doing something like:

```
var q = gc.Cypher
    .Match("(movie:Movie)")
    .OptionalMatch("(movie)<-[r]-(person:Person)")
    .Return(() => new
    {
        Movie = Return.As<Node<string>>("movie"),
        Roles = Return.As<IEnumerable<string>>("collect([person.name, head(split(lower(type(r)), '_')), r.roles])")
    });

    var res = q.Results;
```

You could either `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>()` the Movie node, at your leisure, or write a strongly typed class.

In terms of a 'dynamic' object, I don't know how you were wanting to interact with the `collect` part of the return statement, if this doesn't help, you might need to update the question to show a usage expectation.

Comment: Your first solution is what I need since it keeps the dynamic nature of the query, many thanks!