# Neo4J C# How to receive different type of Nodes and use them

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Lets say for example I have 3 type of nodes `TypeA TypeB TypeC`
and all of the types are inheriting from a `Parent` type which includes the basic info of node for me,
I have this query for example :

```
var graphResult = graphClient.Cypher
    .Unwind(Nodes, "singleNode")
    .Match("p = (innerNode:TypeA{Id:singleNode.Id}) -[r:CONTAINS {solutionId:{innerSolutionId}}] - ()")
            .WithParam("innerSolutionId", solutionId)
            .Return(p => new
                   {
                      Nodes = Neo4jClient.Cypher.Return.As<IEnumerable<Neo4JNodeDSO>>("nodes(p)"),
                      Relationships = Neo4jClient.Cypher.Return.As<IEnumerable<Neo4JLinkDSO>>("rels(p)")
                   }).Results;
```

The Nodes that I return are from the Parent type and does not contain all the data of the childrens type, is there a way to devide some how that when I receive data I will have also the properties that belong to TypeA/TypeB/TypeC? and that are not in the parent object? (A way to receive the whole data of every node and not just deserialize it to the Parent Type ? )

Thanks alot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Not as the specific `type` - you can get it as `dynamic` but you still need to know the type in the long run, this answer: [Returning multi value in dynamic query using neo4j client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008354/returning-multi-value-in-dynamic-query-using-neo4j-client#36008960) might help as you can bung it out as dynamic - (see the last 'code section').

Comment: Eventualy I have decided to make a query to every node type I don't know if its so incorrect but I just think I will have to make all the converts anyway and if my graph has 1k nodes I will find myself trying to organize too much nodes and understand which node is from which type.. Thanks anyway :)